# show only the selected column in the datagridview from xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagrid

I'm trying to show the datagridview with only selected column from the xml
The Xml file look like this

```
<record>
<studentrecord firstname="james" lastname = "peter" id ="23"/>
<studentrecord firstname="kevin" lastname = "jerry" id ="12"/>
</record>
```

I can bring all the 3 attributes (firstname,lastname,id) in grid but i want only the firstname and id to be dispalyed in grid,Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dgv.Columns["lastname"].Visible = false;
```